# Can we map same register address to multiple slave in MODBUS TCP IP

Tags: c, modbus-tcp

I am working on MODBUS TCP/IP server in c. For this development I am using libmodbus (stephane) library. How can I configure same register address to the multiple slave.

Basically, I am developing one MODBUS TCP/IP gateway. There is 10 same type of sensor connected to this gateway. After configuring this gateway with MODBUS TCP/IP Client (PC based software). I want to read parameter of all this parameter through same register address like 10000 for param-1, 10001 for param-2 of all sensor. Can we do that or we need to allocate a different register to all the sensor parameter?

Explanation:
Basically, Support I have one PC on which we installed kepware software (MODBUS-TCP client). Now we connect one Gateway device (MODBUS-TCP server). We have connected 10 devices to this Gateway device through a wired connection. Now as per my understanding if I want to configure client then one way is just allocate 10 register address for each device parameter like 10000 for device-1, 10001 for device-2 and so on. But if all devices are in the same category then I think this is the wrong way for development. So can we do like allocating each device as one unic number and get their parameter value of the device through register address 10000. If its possible then can you explain to me how to achieve this.

[Devices are connected to the server through UART, I2C etc. But the parameter of all devices is the same as voltage and current. So, Can I able to use only 2 registers for voltage and current? If yes then do you have any reference how to use that?]

If any reference or sample code then its helpful for me.

Comment: You should make your question more clear. Do you mean when a client connects to your gateway's server part and requests to read register address 10000 your gateway should query all devices for param-1 and combine this to the result to be sent to the client? Maybe you should describe the communication flow with requests, addresses and responses for an example with 2 or 3 devices. something like this: cliend sends read request 1 for register 10000 to gateway, gateway does something (what?) with the request and communicates (how?) with the devices, gateway sends response for request 1.

Comment: Hi Bodo, I added the explanation in question.

Comment: What do you mean with "through a wired connection"? A serial connection? How many registers does every slave device have? Do you want to address all registers on all slave devices? Modbus/TCP contains an address byte, maybe you can use this to address one of your 10 slaves.

Comment: Serial as well as I2C. But parameter is same, like voltage, current. @2 register. @Yes. How?

Comment: What you answered in the comment should be added **to the question**. Additional question for clarification: Do the devices talk modbus protocol? In this case you could forward the communication between the modbus client and your devices. If the devices use other protocols you will mainly implement a modbus slave and it's your decision if you use the modbus slave address or register address blocks to select a specific device.

Comment: Do the devices talk modbus protocol? : NO. Devices are connected to the server through UART, I2C etc. But the parameter of all devices is the same as voltage and current. So, Can I able to use only 2 registers for voltage and current? If yes then do you have any reference how to use that?

Comment: Please **edit your question to add all additional information** instead of answering questions in additional comments.

Comment: Do you understand my question?

Answer (score 2):

In theory the Modbus/TCP protocol contains a slave address byte. This is intended for gateways that forward the communication between Modbus/TCP and Modbus/RTU. It can also be used to implement some virtual slaves or different register mappings in a single Modbus/TCP slave. So you could, for example, use slave address `1` with register address `10000` to read the voltage from device 1, slave address `2` with register address `10000` to read the voltage from device 2 etc.

I think the `master` branch version of `libmodbus` doesn't give you access to the slave address byte for your own purposes, so you might have to modify the library to implement this.

That's why it may be best to define register address blocks for your devices, e.g. use addresses `10000` and `10001` for voltage and current of device 1, `10002` and `10003` for voltage and current of device 2 etc. (Or reserve some space for the devices and use something like `10000`/`10001` for device 1, `10010`/`10011` for device 2 etc.)

With the `master` branch version of `libmodbus` you can define a mapping structure and run a cyclic function that reads the values and puts them into the register mapping memory. If you already have a memory-mapped structure with all the values you might be able to use this existing memory for your register mapping. In this case the register layout will match your existing data structure.

Cyclic polling your devices to copy all values to a register structure in memory might be sufficient for a small amount of data.

If you use a pull request that adds callback support you can implement callback functions that read or write the valules from/to the device only when replying to a specific Modbus request. This might be better suited for large data structures.

I don't have example code available.

Comment: Thanks Bodo, Do you know any reference for MODBUS TCP/IP

Comment: @harshalbhavsar Ask your favourite search engine. Examples: http://www.simplymodbus.ca/TCP.htm https://www.prosoft-technology.com/kb/assets/intro_modbustcp.pdf